# Problems with making image of Windows - clonezilla, system image recovery, veracrypt

Tags: windows-10, partition-recovery, clonezilla, veracrypt

I want to have an ideal copy of the whole Windows 10 I have installed and configured recently, as well as main application I am using (already installed and configured).
I would like to store this image of Windows at my external drive.

First of all I tried to do it with Windows System Image Revcovery Tools.
I have to abandon this way, probably because all my disk is encrypted with VeraCrypt (I got few error during, and I guess it is the reason).

After I realize that I turned to the way with CloneZilla.
I have burned it into USB and run partition image option in order to save all my C partition (system) into external drive. There were some error at the beginning but all the process succeded. However I do not have the catalog which one the clonezilla image should be placed on. It disappeared (before I have created empty directory for the Clonezilla image, and during clonezilla setup I have navigated to it). During next clonezilla setup it doesn't find my image I have done, but the external disk is used in 15 % of space what is correct.

Can't I see and manage clonezilla image on Windows ? Even if, why clonezilla can't see it ?

**What do you recommend me to do ?**

Do you think I am making an error while setting up CloneZilla or do you recommend me to use another tool ?

I want to have an image of the system. The whole system and applications I have on my partition C:/ (which is on the hard disk fully encrypted with VeraCrypt). I want to be able to back my system to the situation from the moment of making image. And I want to be able to store this image file/directory on my external disk which would be encrypted with VeraCrypt as well. But I have one other external disk which can be used, and it is not encrypted.

Comment: "I got few error during, and I guess it is the reason" - You should ask a question, provide us with the errors, so you can confirm that is indeed the case.

Comment: What @Ramhound said. If you're getting errors, it is absolutely necessary to share them if you're looking for answers. Without the errors we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Thank for reply, so I stucked in the situation which one I have described here in details: https://superuser.com/questions/1245609/windows-system-image-restoring-failed-0x800703ed