# WIndows System Image Restoring failed 0x800703ED

Tags: filesystems, system-restore

I have done system image succefully. The system image consist of 2 partition C (NTFS) which one is system Windows 10 and the small one for booting (500 mb, normally this one is not visible from Windows explorer, but is done while instal is run).

Now I am trying to restore this one and after it starting to do the work it is failing.

System Image is found correctly, then I do not have an option to format disk (in this step s written that in case this option is disabled I can install drivers for drive), but anyway I do not want to format this disk. I just want to restore C partition.

Then after a moment when restoring is started and some percent of the work is done I am getting the error like this:

```
The system image restore failed.

Error details: The volume does not contain a recognized file system. Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted. (0x800703ED)
```

What can I do now ? How to go step further with this issue ? Any suggestions ?

I have run chkdsk and there is not error. Below the log.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk
The type of the file system is NTFS.

WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  234496 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  6248 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  322314 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
  43910 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  35854168 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

 112639999 KB total disk space.
  31601104 KB in 147759 files.
    102588 KB in 43911 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    341347 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  80594960 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  28159999 total allocation units on disk.
  20148740 allocation units available on disk.
```

edit:

The whole disk where the partition C, small partition and one more partition (not important for this scenario) is placed is encrypted with VeraCrypt.

Comment: The problem is VeraCrypt

Comment: Thank you the answer. So how I can work around this ? 
Should I suspend the Windows Image System way ? I have tried with clonezilla which is not working as well. Can you suggest me any alternative in order to keep my Windows current state able to be restored in the future ?